# How to use browser parallel loading but still maintain the order of scripts using RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I have this friend, who hates `RequireJS`, I recently started using it & I like it, but by his arguments, I started feeling like I might end up like him and give up using `RequireJS`.

```
require(['one'],function(){
    require(['two'],function(){
        require(['three'],function(){

        });
    });
});
```

Above code is fairly straight-forward, `three` depends on `two` & `two` depends on `one`. That makes the browser to load `one` first & then `two` & then `three` in sequence, that's how `requirejs` handles it, which makes the site real slow if there are lots of these kinds of dependencies.

Browser parallel loading feature it not used at all.

I want to know if there is any way in which `require` loads all these files asyncronously but makes sure to maintain the order in their execution, so that browser parallelism can be used.

Comment: Why not simply append the `<script>` tags to the end of the body in the HTML in the order required?

Comment: well, yes, that's the non-require way of doing it !

Comment: If some code depends on another why not use `define` and crete module?

Comment: Are you sure your read the [online documentation](http://requirejs.org/)?

Comment: @kryger I've read the docs, though not very thorough about how it works. I'm a beginner with `RequireJs`, would be great if you can provide me some code that takes advantage of browser parallel loading & also maintain the order. I'm not very clear with `define` & `require`, both kinda appears the same.

Comment: I don't think the answers here really help. However, I think [this post by James Burke](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/requirejs/Xh0W2qpWeeA/UMNASJYQRrQJ) (the author) does help - I just haven't had a chance to try it otherwise I'd post an answer. The idea is to create an optimized module that only includes other ones and has an empty define() so no dependencies are executed. This allows you to download the optimized bundle without resolving dependencies. Then once you know its dependencies has been downloaded and executed, you can execute the dependent modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RequireJS is a powerful tool that allows us to load script asynchronously (means we start the loading of each one, and don't wait until it is actually loaded), but still manage dependencies (if one file depends on another, we wanna wake sure the dependency will be loaded beforehand). The way you use RequireJS is not what it is made for. The callback function inside the require is called as soon as the dependency module is loaded ('one', 'two', 'three'). So you are just loading all the modules sequentially, not asynchronously (one is loaded -> callback function is called -> two is loaded -> callback function is called -> three is loaded -> callback function is called). That makes no sense. The way it is supposed to be:

in your HTML file:

```
<script data-main='main.js' src='require.js'></script>
```

in your main.js file (some file you wrote inside your script tag as `data-main`):

```
require(['one'], function(one){
    one.function1();
});
```

in one.js:

```
define(['two', 'three'], function(two, three) {
    return {
        function1 : function() {
            two.function2();
            three.function3();
            console.log('one');
        }
    }
});
```

in two.js:

```
define([], function() {
    return {
        function2 : function() {
            console.log('two');
        }
    }
});
```

in three.js:

```
define([], function() {
    return {
        function3 : function() {
            console.log('three');
        }
    }
});
```

In my example 'one' depends on 'two' and 'three' (it requires function2() from 'two' and function3() from 'three'), 'two' and 'three' have no dependencies. This example code assumes all the files are in one folder (including require.js). As a result, we see 'two', 'three', 'one' printed (in that order).

Comment: great, define loads async but makes sure the execution-order is maintained.

Comment: The OP's example will load in a sequence of three steps like:

`[one.js] -> [two.js] -> [three.js].`

This example will load in a sequence of three steps like:

`[main.js] -> [one.js] -> [two.js, three.js]`. It depends on the size of the files but that might or might not be an improvement.  The biggest improvement will come from the fact that, once you have a main.js, you can run the r.js optimizer on it to build everything to one module.

Answer (score 0):

Although RequireJS uses AMD model for loading scripts, we can still manage module evaluation order by ourselves. If you don't want to use `define()`, you can use a special plugin called **order!**. It works for RequireJS 1.0 API. It allows to fetch files asynchronously, but make evaluation in a specific order: http://requirejs.org/docs/1.0/docs/api.html#order.

Comment: can you please give a quick example of how to use `define` & still enjoy browser parallel loading ? I'm trying to understand, but can't find how it works.

Comment: Also, are there any `>2.0` version solution ? (`order` is not supported in `>=2.0`)

Answer (score -1):

The [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24500340/69697) will work nicely for most use-cases, especially because  it will usually make sense to [use r.js to bundle everything](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html), which makes parallel loading a moot point.  However, this solution does not actually allow for loading all modules in parallel, instead either loading in a 3-step sequence that looks like: `[main.js] -> [one.js] -> [two.js, three.js]` (if you don't use r.js to package the files all to one module) or a single load of one packaged file (if you do use r.js to package all the files to one module).

If you do in fact want to make the files load in a single parallel step like: `[one.js, two.js, three.js]`, you have a couple of options:

---

**A. Use RequireJS 1.0 + order plugin**

This one is covered in [gthacoder's other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24500107/69697).

---

**B. Wrap the scripts so that Require can load them, then execute them in a separate stage**

This introduces some complexity, but is very reliable. The key thing is that every module that you want to load in parallel should contain a named module inside it that does not match the name you use to load the file. This will prevent the module from executing until you explicitly tell it to:

**one.js**

```
define('one-inner', ['two-inner'], function () {
  ...
});
```

**two.js**

```
define('two-inner', ['three-inner'], function () {
  ...
});
```

**three.js**

```
define('three-inner', function () {
  ...
});
```

**Your page or main.js file**

```
// 1. Require loads one.js, two.js, and three.js in parallel,
// but does not execute the modules, because nothing has called
// them by the correct name yet.
require(['one', 'two', 'three']), function () {

       // 2. Kickstart execution of the modules
       require(['one-inner'], function () {
             ....
       }
});
```